# Concatenating string from two cells when text entered, then closing the loop

Tags: string, excel, vba

When entering data into a cell, I would like to grab the string from another cell, and concatenate the two. When the cell is blank, this does not happen. The issue is that my If-statement looks for a non-null cell and concatenates the string. This is fine for the first text input, but after it concatenates the two strings, the cell is no longer blank and the loop continues, constantly appending the same string to the growing concatenation. How can I make the loop stop after concatenating once?

```
If Sheets(1).Range("AC5").Value <> "" Then
    Sheets(1).Range("AC5").Value = Sheets(1).Range("k5").Value & " - " & Sheets(1).Range("AC5").Value

Else: Sheets(1).Range("AC5").Value = ""
End If
```

Comment: I assume this is in the worksheet_change event.  Try `application.enableevents = False` at the beginning and turn it true at the end.

Comment: Sorry, it is a selection change event, unfortunately this solution did not work.

Comment: Show more of the code, there is no reason in what you have shown for the endless loop.  Also what is in your worksheet_change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `InStr` to check if the header cell is already concatenated:

```
If InStr(Sheets(1).Range("AC5").Value, Sheets(1).Range("k5").Value) = 1 Then
 ....
```